# My own domain redirects automatically to mysite.000webhostapp.com

Tags: shared-hosting, namecheap, laravel

In [namecheap.com](http://namecheap.com), I have the following settings:

Custom DNS: **ns01.000webhost.com** and **ns02.000webhost.com**

How to link my own domain to mysite.000webhostapp.com with **https** connection

i.e. https://mydomain.me without redirects automatically to https://mysite.000webhostapp.com

**Edit:** my domain accessed correctly now (with no redirect) but cannot be accessed over HTTPS which is the requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying... is `ns01.000webhost.com` and `ns02.000webhost.com` the intended NAMESERVERS? Where is the redirect occurring? Is `mysite.000webhostapp.com` an external host? Is `mysite.000webhostapp.com` expecting requests to `https://mysite.me`?

Comment: Sorry I mean https://mydomain.me .. They are NAMESERVERS .. redirect occuring when requesting mydomain.me .. mysite.000webhostapp.com is where I deployed my website for free .. expecting requests to https://mydomain.me is just https://mydomain.me linked with my deployed website

Comment: You should add the additional information to your question (from the deleted answer)... that your domain now resolves correctly (with no redirect) to the required host, but cannot be accessed over HTTPS - which is the requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> mysite.000webhostapp.com is where I deployed my website **for free**

HTTPS on *your own domain* does not appear to be supported on "free" accounts. It looks like you'll need to upgrade to their "premium [paid-for] hosting service" in order to do this. From [their knowledge base article](https://www.000webhost.com/website-faq/ssl-certificates-do-you-support-ssl-31):

> **SSL certificates, do you support SSL?**
>
> By default, all 000webhostapp.com subdomains are covered with 000webhost’s SSL.
>
> However you can upgrade your account to our premium hosting service at https://www.hostinger.com/special/000webhost and enjoy full benefits of SSL and other unlimited features for best price on the market.